# how to make a BufferedReader in C

Tags: c, input

I am really new programming in C. How can I do the same in C, maybe in a more simple way than the one I do in Java?

Each line of the input has two integers: X and Y separated by a space.

12 1
12 3
23 4
9 3

```c
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(in);

int  n;
int k;

double sol;
String line = "";
line = buf.readLine();

while( line != null && !line.equals("")){
    String data [] = line.split(" ");
    n = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
    k = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
    calculus (n,k);
    line = buf.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Do you care if it's buffered or is that just what you're used to? Reading files in C is easy, I have no idea about buffering though.

Comment: I just want to read input, i dont need buffer.

Comment: Might help - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf.

Comment: I actually didn't catch at first that you're reading from stdin. It's somewhat confusing because there's no point to buffering that. You may want to make it more clear that you're not using files..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No compiler, so please fix as needed. Also the variable decalrations are C++ style

```
#include <stdio.h>

...

while (!feof(stdin)) {
    int n = 0, k = 0;
    if (scanf("%d %d\n", &n, &k) != 2) continue;
    // do something with n and k
}
```

C++ solution (with streams) may be simpler still

Comment: This must be a first (certainly a first for me!) - a -1 answer accepted. @peiska - thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `fgets()` to read a line of text and `sscanf()` to parse it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, k;
    char line[64]; // adjust size as necessary

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) && sscanf(line, "%d %d", &n, &k) == 2)
        printf("n=%d, k=%d\n", n, k); // dummy code

    return 0;
}
```

Using `scanf()` alone to read directly from `stdin` might be possible with scansets, but it's not as easy as it looks because whitespace characters (including newlines) are skipped.

Answer (score 0):

```
fscanf(filehandle, "%d %d\n", n, k);
```

Comment: shouldn't work as expected because `fscanf()` skips whitespace

Answer (score 0):

The file variable is called [`FILE`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/FILE/)

To open a file use [`fopen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/)

Reading and writing are done with [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) and [`fputs()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fputs/)

This is all in `stdio.h`.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *input = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    char text[100]; // Where we'll put our text we read
    fgets(text, 100, input); // Get up to 100 chars, stops at the first newline
    puts(text); // In your example, this should print out "12 1"
    fgets(text, 100, input); // Get the next up to 100 chars
    puts(text); // Prints "12 3"
    return 0;
}
```

Let me know if there's anything wrong with the code, I don't have a C compiler with me.